# Access to smart contract's value in Node-js

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs

I am working on a simple Truffle project that just shows `"Yerevan is love"`. My contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
contract TEST{
   bytes note="Yerevan is love";
   function fname() public view returns(string memory){
      return string(note);
   }
}
```

And by app.js i could create a communication between the contract and JavaScript but i don't know what is an appropriate code to show `"Yerevan is love"` in Node-js .My app.js code:

```
var Web3=require("web3");
var web3= new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
var fs=require('fs') ;
var jsonFile="C:/Users/lenovo/node_modules/Yerevan/build/contracts/TEST.json";
var parsed=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(jsonFile));
var abi=parsed.abi;
var myContract= new 
    web3.eth.Contract(abi,"0xEC3B8e1607C92D5695dE5FaCdE3db76EBff7f5eA" );
```

This app.js has not a code to show `"Yerevan is love"` because i don't know that. Please provide the appropriate code and a guide for a beginner man.

Comment: `myContract.methods.fname().call().then(function(x) {console.log(x);});`.

Comment: Here is the related doc to what proposed @goodvibration: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working js script example of your contract:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
let abi = [
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "fname",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

let addressOfContract = '<PUT_ADDRESS_OF_CONTRACT_HERE>'
let endPoint = '<PUT_YOUR_ENDPOINT_HERE>'

// Destinguishes browser from server side
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3 !== "undefined") {
    // we are in the browser and metamask injected a provider and is running
    web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // we are in the server side and metmask is not available
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
        endPoint
    );
    web3 = new Web3(provider);
}

testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, addressOfContract)

testContract.methods.fname().call().then(console.log)
```

Comment: Thank you, Is there any code to see the result of `testContract.methods.fname().call().then(console.log) ` in browser by Node-js or another tool? Is an appropriate code for that?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the below command after the last line you embedded in the question:

```
myContract.methods.fname().call().then(function(instance){console.log(instance)});
```

Answer (score 1):

With the JavaScript code you provided in the question, you just can define the given contract. You need to use another method of `web3` that executes a solidity function. For executing a solidity function with `web3` methods you should try a command like this:

```
contract_name.methods.function_name(<arguments ...>).send({from:<sender address>, value:<ether values>, gas:<gas value to be used>, gasPrice:<price and fee for a gas used>});
```

or

```
contract_name.methods.function_name(<arguments ...>).call();
```

The first command changes state and is appropriate to setter functions. The second command doesn't change state and is appropriate to getter functions. After that, you can use `.then(console.log)` to see the result in console. So, the solution is one of followed commands:

```
contract_name.methods.function_name(<arguments ...>).send({from:<sender address>, value:<ether values>, gas:<gas value to be used>, gasPrice:<price and fee for a gas used>}).then(console.log);
```

or

```
contract_name.methods.function_name(<arguments ...>).call().then(console.log);
```

Comment: You are missing the parenthesis after the function name. It should be like this `contract_name.methods.function_name().call()`. The parenthesis are required, even when the function doesn't take any input parameters.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your pointing. I edited that.